# Why is the Bayes predictor of the $0-1$ loss the maximum a posteriori?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

> Let $(X,Y) \in \Bbb X \times \Bbb Y$ be jointly distributed according
>   to distribution $P$.  Let $h: \Bbb X \rightarrow \tilde {\Bbb Y}$,
>   where $\tilde {\Bbb Y}$ is a predicted output. $ $Let $L(h,P) \equiv
>  \Bbb E_P[l(Y, h(X))]$ where $l$ is some loss function.
>
> Show that $f = \arg \min_h L(h,P) = \arg \max_y p_{Y|X}(y|x)$ if $l$ is the
>    $0-1$ loss function: $l(Y, h(X)) = \{1 \text{ if } h(X) \ne y, 0 \text{ otherwise }\}$

I'm not even sure how to start this.  Can someone give me some suggestions?  I know I have to show that the maximum $y$ of the conditional distribution is the minimum argument, but from there I don't understand where to go.

Comment: Consider using$$\Bbb E_P[l(Y, h(X))]=\Bbb E^X[\Bbb E^{Y|X}\{l(Y, h(X))|X\}]$$

Comment: @Xi'an I'm a little confused as to the definition of $\Bbb E_P[]$ now.  By law of total expectation: $\Bbb E_X[X] = \Bbb E_Y[\Bbb E_{X|Y}[X|Y]]$, and so by $\Bbb E_P = \Bbb E_{X}[\Bbb E_{Y|X}]$ this means that $\Bbb E_P = \Bbb E_Y$.  But doesn't $\Bbb E_P[] $ mean $\Bbb E_{(x,y) \text{ ~ } P}[]$?  How are $\Bbb E_{(x,y) \text{ ~ } P}$ and $\Bbb E_Y$ the same?

Comment: Just think about it this way:  $E^{Y|X}\{l(Y, h(X))|X\}$ is a function of $X$ only.